PHP / Windows / Selenium : use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions; doesn't work when included from another file
I'm running PHP on Windows and executing Selenium scripts. If I put the whole script in the same file, everything works fine but when I try to isolate the initialization of Selenium in a separate file, it doesn't work anymore and I don't get any error message in my logs.
Main file:
<?php
global $driver;
global $host;
global $log;

include("../common/common.php");
require_once "../../vendor/autoload.php";
include("includes/selenium_init.php");
include("includes/selenium_prep.php");
include("includes/selenium_fct.php");

...etc
in selenium_init.php I have:
echo "***** SELENIUM INIT ********<br>";
use Facebook\WebDriver\Chrome\ChromeOptions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverActions;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\RemoteWebDriver;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverBy;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverExpectedCondition;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Remote\DesiredCapabilities;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverWait;
use Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeoutException;
$host = 'http://localhost:4444/';
$options = new ChromeOptions();
$options->addArguments(['--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled']);
$extensions = explode(",",  "mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij,cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm");
echo "aaaa";
for ($b = 0; $b < sizeof($extensions); $b++) 
    {
        $ext_version = trim(updateExtension($extensions[$b]));
    echo $ext_version."<br>";
    $extension_path = "C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default\\Extensions\\" . $extensions[$b] . "\\" . $ext_version;
    echo $extension_path."<br>";
    if (is_dir($extension_path))
        {
            echo "found<br>";
            $options->addArguments(['--load-extension=' . $extension_path]);
        }
    else
        {
            echo "path not found<br>";
        }
}
            
$options->setExperimentalOption('excludeSwitches', ['enable-automation']);
$options->addArguments(['--window-size=1920,1080']);
$capabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
$capabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);
$driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $capabilities);
$driver->manage()->deleteAllCookies();

echo "***** SELENIUM DONE ********<br>";

When I execute this combination, i only get this:
***** SELENIUM INIT ********
***** SELENIUM DONE ********

And nothing happens, Selenium doesn't open Chrome like it should do. The echo "aaaa" is not executed and this portion of the script is completely ignored.
If I put everything together in the main file, it works fine. It doesn't make sense to me but I'm probably missing something obvious.
Here is the output when I put everything in the same file:
***** SELENIUM INIT ********
aaaa
8.12.8_1
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\mlomiejdfkolichcflejclcbmpeaniij\8.12.8_1
found
1.57.0_1
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm\1.57.0_1
found
***** SELENIUM DONE ********

Do you have any idea?
thanks!
